# Job application. Design without background information?!

Tags: interaction-design, design, wireframe

I applied for a UX job, and I got a task to complete to show my skills... I got a task to redesign one screen of their app, and they didn't give me any user researches, personas, user scenarios...nothing, just access to their web app, and the job to redesign one certain screen.

They are very established company, and their business is about that app, so by not providing me any details for doing successful UX job probably was intentional. They told me to provide them only a final wireframe and the process (why I did it that way).

My question is what approach should I use and what to do about the lack of info? I don't want to send them emails asking for information, but I am not sure how to do it successfuly without it?

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of established companies that don't have a clue what UX is, so them giving you no background information isn't necessarily intentional.  (Find out if they do think the job involves nothing more than drawing the UI.)

Don't be afraid to ask for more information. In a good company a large part of a UX job is asking tons of questions to make sure you fully understand requirements before creating a design. Asking questions now will both demonstrate your willingness to learn and will give you a sense of whether the company culture will let you ask the questions you need to in order to do your job well.

If their omission of the earlier parts of the design process *is* deliberate, you could still create a few pages explaining some fictitious user research and user scenarios so that you have a basis to justify the decisions made in the later part of the design.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do a basic heuristic evaluation without too much domain knowledge. For anything you suggest over and above that, document the assumptions you've made about the users of the application, and explain how you would go about more realistic user research and validating your proposed improvements were you actually working for the company.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose whenever you work on a ux project, you ***have*** to have at least some personas and/or user scenarios – whether *they* provide personas and/or user scenarios to you or not. So I fear you'll have to think of building your own personas and user scenarios. Be sure that you document those personas and user scenarios – at least I would recommend that you (of course) should include them in your presentation – especially since they are also interested in the process – *why you did it that way*.

PS: working self employed you'd quite often have to come up with your own user scenarios, because nobody else would write them for you – at least that's how my work routine works – and that made me think that maybe it was half-intentional to not provide anything to you, so you can also prove how *autonomous* you can work.